# How to split a string at the first colon

Tags: php, regex

```
$str = "X-Storage-Url: https://pathofanapi";
```

I would like to split this into an array ("X-Storage-Url", "https://pathofanapi").

Could someone tell me the regex for this ? Regex has always been my weakness.

Thanks.

Comment: you dont need a regex for this

Comment: No regex required, just the explode method.

Answer (score 3):

```
$array = array_map('trim', explode(':', $str, 2));
```

Comment: It would probably be safest to use the 3rd limit parameter of the explode function, that way your not relying on the space being there.

Comment: "Each header field consists of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. [...] The field value **MAY** be preceded by any amount of LWS, though a single SP is preferred." [RFC 2616](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.2) This will fail if the HTTP-Header has more or less than one space beetween `name` and `field value`.

Answer (score 0):

As it's been said, `explode` is the right tool to do this job.

However, if you really want a regex, here is a way to do:

**with preg_match:**

```
$str = "X-Storage-Url: https://pathofanapi";
preg_match('/^([^:]+):\s*(.*)$/', $str, $m);
print_r($m);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => X-Storage-Url: https://pathofanapi
    [1] => X-Storage-Url
    [2] => https://pathofanapi
)
```

**or with preg_split;**

```
$arr = preg_split('/:\s*/', $str, 2);
print_r($arr);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => X-Storage-Url
    [1] => https://pathofanapi
)
```